# how can I set the data offset on an mdadm device?

Tags: mdadm

I am trying to recover from a degraded RAID array. I stupidly used `mdadm --create` somewhere along the way, and now a couple of my devices have incorrect superblocks. Luckily I kept a copy of the old superblocks:

```
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 7318877d:a7538da2:dbdff5e9:613cc676
           Name : vern:2
  Creation Time : Thu Oct 20 21:58:58 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 1953517954 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 1953517568 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953517568 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 3dc62a0d:71ad83cf:f0dea827:6919f67c

    Update Time : Mon Mar  4 19:53:30 2013
       Checksum : a1b473f6 - correct
         Events : 152880

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K
```

Comparing this to the new superblock:

```
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 53e45e96:bc283e07:77748762:24fade80
           Name : Velma:2  (local to host Velma)
  Creation Time : Fri May  3 17:35:48 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 1953257858 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
     Array Size : 1953257472 (1862.77 GiB 2000.14 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953257472 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : bae87034:ba42a7ed:c4fa2854:5888d619

    Update Time : Fri May  3 17:35:48 2013
       Checksum : b3c99dd4 - correct
         Events : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K
```

The major difference here is in the data offset. If I can manually set the data offset back to 2048 sectors, then I stand a fighting chance of recovering the data in the RAID volume.

So... how can I set this offset?

Comment: How did you create RAIDs with different offsets at all? I don't see any possibility in `man mdadm` how to influence that.

Comment: This is an old RAID array that has been through many versions of Ubuntu... as I've been replacing disks with different versions of `mdadm`, they have been added to the array with different data offsets.

Comment: Oh, that makes it even more fun. I guess in this case you  have to write the respective field of the superblock (and maybe a checksum) directly (without a tool). Is it an option for you to get access to the data by a work-around, make a backup and completely recreate the array afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer deep within the bowels of http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.raid/38674: it turns out that there is a branch of `mdadm` that allows custom data offsets. To get it:

```
git clone -b data_offset git://neil.brown.name/mdadm
cd mdadm
make
```

This adds the ability to set the data offset on a per-device basis, by appending the device id with a : and the offset. For example:

```
./mdadm --create /dev/md2 --level=5 -raid-devices=3 --assume-clean \ 
    /dev/sdb3:89088 /dev/sdd1:1024 /dev/sdc3:131072
```

I had to divide the offset by 2, as it is in K rather than sectors. I think that I could have used

```
./mdadm --create /dev/md2 --level=5 -raid-devices=3 --assume-clean \ 
    /dev/sdb3:178176s /dev/sdd1:2048s /dev/sdc3:262144s
```

instead, but I haven't verified this.

Anyway, this built the array with the correct size and I have managed to recover some of the data from it. Result!

Comment: newer mdadm version (>=3.3) have the --data-offset option